# What happens to intrinsic factor exactly at the terminal ileum, where B12 is absorbed?

Tags: physiology, vitamins, gastroenterology

IF is very important for IF-dependent B12 absorption in the terminal ileum, the mechanism by which most of dietary B12 is absorbed. The B12-IF complex bind to IF receptors on enterocytes, but does the complex in its entirety get absorbed, or does B12 alone get absorbed and the IF is left outside?

The latter mechanism I came across in source 1 (see below), which stated the following:

> IF-B12 complex binds to specific receptors. Following this, the vitamin B12 is absorbed into the cytosol of the enterocyte by endocytosis, leaving behind the IF at the brush border.

However, several other books and articles (like 2-4) rather vaguely state that the IF-B12 complex is absorbed into the enterocyte. I've found two articles that discuss the existence of these two viewpoints, (5 and 6), but they are kind of old (from 1965 and 1989 respectively) and I don't know if the "mystery's been solved" as it were.

Sources:

1. Concise Textbook of Human Physiology ([this specific page](https://books.google.iq/books?id=tpxYDwAAQBAJ&pg=PA292&dq=transcobalamin%20ii%20inside%20enterocytes%20or%20in%20blood&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiNt9D95PTpAhXHM5oKHclWDh0Q6AEIOjAC#v=onepage&q=transcobalamin%20ii%20inside%20enterocytes%20or%20in%20blood&f=false))
2. [The Mechanism of Absorption of Vitamin B12 (cobalamin) in the GI Tract](https://www.ebmconsult.com/articles/vitamin-b12-absorption-mechanism-intestine-intrinsic-factor)
3. Marks' Essential Medical Biochemistry ([this specific page](https://books.google.iq/books?id=MgqI-pfk45QC&pg=PA511&dq=if+vitamin+b12+is+ingested+in+its+free+form+it+binds+to+r-binder&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwj939CX4_TpAhVkxKYKHV6oD_kQ6AEISzAE#v=onepage&q=if%20vitamin%20b12%20is%20ingested%20in%20its%20free%20form%20it%20binds%20to%20r-binder&f=false))
4. Textbook of Pharmacology ([this page](https://books.google.iq/books?id=51ozlZRBvQwC&pg=RA3-PA7&dq=what%20happens%20to%20intrinsic%20factor%20after%20absorption&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjTg9rb5vTpAhWwQkEAHYTIDdMQ6AEIQjAD#v=onepage&q=what%20happens%20to%20intrinsic%20factor%20after%20absorption&f=false))
5. [Intrinsic Factor](https://www.gastrojournal.org/article/S0016-5085(19)34568-8/pdf)
6. [Vitamin B12 absorption and malabsorption](https://gut.bmj.com/content/gutjnl/30/12/1686.full.pdf)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After reversible attachment of intrinsic factor-cobalamin complex to its ileal surface receptor, an energy-dependent
process prevents removal of the complex from the cell surface by EDTA or acid; cobalamin dissociates
from intrinsic factor and, as suggested by previous
workers, binds to a molecule antigenically similar to
transcobalamin II; and  intrinsic factor is slowly(after some hours)degraded and forms breakdown products that are *detectable in ileal extracts*.

References 
Textbook of Pathology [Page 318](https://books.google.co.in/books?id=LXKSDwAAQBAJ&pg=PA321&lpg=PA321&dq=harsh+mohan+pathology+page+280&source=bl&ots=7SXXt1lp05&sig=ACfU3U3vtndXFjztz6pswi3LwsbRJCxl8w&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwib9J6Vn_rpAhXIR30KHbmuCFsQ6AEwA3oECAQQAQ#v=onepage&q=harsh%20mohan%20pathology%20page%20280&f=false)

One article
[Intrinsic factor mediated absorption of cobalamin](https://www.jci.org/articles/view/110788/files/pdf)

Recent articles-
[Physiology of absorption of vitamin b12](https://www.medscape.com/answers/1152670-77124/what-is-the-physiology-of-absorption-of-vitamin-b-12#qna)

Comment: This article is also quite old, newer articles than it suggest that the issue was still controversial at the time

Comment: @Dahen yes I agree. Though I have added one recent article proving the degradation of IF. However upon more research I found some articles stating the controversial fate of IF.

Comment: Thanks for going out of your way to look for so many sources, I appreciate it.

Comment: @Dahen thanks. I too got to know about this. It is a good question.